# Нужны те CLIENT_ID у которых ПЕРВЫЙ договор был заключен > '20200701'

Tags: sql

Есть табл. с CONTRACT_ID, у одного CLIENT_ID их много. Нужны те CLIENT_ID у которых ПЕРВЫЙ договор был заключен > '20200701'

Comment: Здравствуйте! Это мой первый вопрос на stackoverflow, возможно он кажется простым, но я сталкиваюсь с проблемой, в выборку попадают клиенты у который второй или сл. договора > '20200701'

Comment: Используйте [edit] для корректировки вопроса. И добавьте ваш код запроса.

Answer (score 1):

вам нужна группировка по client_id, выборка минимальной даты и условие having для фильтрации. что-то вроде

```
  select client_id
  from x
  group by client_id  
  having min(x.d) > '2020-07-01'
```

Если нужна информация по этим клиентам, то этот запрос джойните к списку клиентов

Comment: Была такая мысль, но как написать  min в having  (having min(x.d) > '2020-07-01') можно подробнее? Мне казалось, что он ругается что 'min' находится не в блоке select

Comment: @Dmitriy конкретный диалект СУБД укажите,если не работает, ибо запрос приведенный выше вполне рабочий. Или мб вы забыли `group  by`

Comment: Спасибо действительно это работает на t-sql.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую, возможно тоже пригодится!

Comment: @Dmitriy не пригодится. я что-то натупил, это не то. удалю коммент

Comment: SELECT
     contr.client_id,STEP_SUM,
        min(contr.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE) over (partition by contr.CLIENT_ID) AS min_CONTRACT_BEGINDATE
  
    FROM  contr
 where  contr.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE >= '20200701'
    group by contr.CLIENT_ID ,contr.CONTRACT_BEGINDATE,STEP_SUM

Comment: В итоге сделал так